# php file returning its own text to XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send a XMLHttpRequest from a html file to a php file. Both are in the same folder and I have XAMPP Apache active and running(if I run the php file by itself, it works as expected).
Problem is, the response from the php file is its own text, instead of what it echoed. The XMLHttpRequest is successful, in the sense that it has a status of 200

Code from the html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ajax 4-Ajax and PHP form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button">Get Name</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",getName);

        function getName()
        {
            var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET","process.php",true);
            xhr.onload=function(){
                console.log("status: "+this.status);
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
            xhr.send();
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code from my process.php file:

```html
<?php 
echo "Processing...";
?>
```

The output I expect when I click the button is for the console to log 200 Processing... but it logs 200 plus the inside of the php file

Comment: you have to load the HTML page from the server. If you load it from a local file, the XMLHttpRequest also goes to the local file, which doesn't run the script.

Comment: Thank you mate, it works! I feel reaaaally noobish now :)

Comment: I'm sorry if the question is a duplicate. I swear I looked for it on google for 30 mins without success.

Comment: I have a library of hundreds of common duplicates like this...

Comment: Aha sorry mate :) Thanks for your help!